# WP8.1 WinRT COMException cause

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, comexception

I'm working on a WP8.1 WinRT project. I'm downloading a file and trying to open it but i get an error ? What is wrong with my code ?

```
 private async void HandleDownloadAsync(DownloadOperation download, bool start)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Progress<DownloadOperation> progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(ProgressCallback);
                        if (start)
                        {
                            await download.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await download.AttachAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
                        }

                        ResponseInformation response = download.GetResponseInformation();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error HandleDownloadAsync: {0}", ex);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        OpenFile();
                    }
                }

        private async void OpenFile()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        StorageFile fileToLaunch = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync(medNameChosen");
                        if (destinationFile.ToString() != null)
                        {
                            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fileToLaunch);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex);
                    }
                }
```

After i run the code below i get the following error:

```
Error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(IStorageFile file)
   at PM.Page.<OpenFile>d__1f.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Tried debugging this with Fiddler yet?

Comment: Did u tried to set manualy the ContentType in the launcheroption (optional parameter for launchfileasync) ?

Comment: I'm new to the WP platform, i don't realy know what to set. I tried to open a MessageDialog instead of opening the file and i get another error:  The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.

Comment: If you get exception with this message "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread." - that is mean that you should to call your method in interface thread. You can do it by Dispatcher .

From UI thread:

var dispatcher = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;

From background:
'code' dispatcher.RunAsync(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
    <lambda for your code which should run on the UI thread>);